# Reading a serialized binary file generated by CArchive MFC in Python

Tags: python, c++, qt, serialization, carchive

I have binary files generated from serialized C++ objects using MFC CArchive. I want to write Python code to read these binary files.

What is an equivalent function or class in Python or pyqt that can read snd deserialized files?

I have looked at the QT `QDataStream` class but I dont know if it is similar to CArchive.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?